# What is the criteria to choose between valueOf() and newInstance()?

Tags: java, factory-method, coding-style

Suppose I have a class ObjectInfo which contains Object name & Object type as String.(I am just cooking up something for the sake of asking the question.)

```
class ObjectInfo {
    String objectName;
    
    String objectType;

    private ObjectInfo(String objectName, String objectType) {
          this.objectName = objectName;
          this.objectType = objectType;
    }
}
```

And If I want to provide a static factory method to creating instances of this class, which of the following two methods is better & why?

```
public static ObjectInfo newInstance(String objectName, String objectType) {
    return new ObjectInfo(objectName, objectType)    
}

public static ObjectInfo valueOf(String objectName, String objectType) {
    return new ObjectInfo(objectName, objectType)    
}
```

Basically, what I want to ask is  when we should use valueOf() & when newInstance()? Is there any conventions among the programmer's community?

Comment: The naming conventions really depend on context.  There's no one rule that says A is better than B.

Comment: What context you are talking about? That's what I want to know

Comment: you have implemented the both same way. SO there is no difference. But i wonder what that new is doing inside both methods :)

Comment: newInstance kind of implies it will always create a new instance, whereas valueOf is less tied to that assumption. Note valueOf() is used in a lot of java.lang classes like Integer etc, where objects _are_ cached for some values...

Comment: How the implementation of these two methods would effect the choice? That's what I want to know

Comment: @user1522820 If you have a map with existing object instances, then you can return an existing object instead of a new one if the values are repeated, as in [Flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public static ObjectInfo newObjectInfo(String objectName, String objectType)
```

For a static factory method, I would use the above naming convention. This is useful if the method consumers want to use static imports:

```
import static foo.ObjectInfo.newObjectInfo;
//....
ObjectInfo info = newObjectInfo(foo, bar);
```

You can see this pattern [in the Guava API](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html).

Comment: I am going to go with this. The name of the method is self-explanatory. According to Josh Bloch in his book Effective Java :- newInstance— newInstance guarantees that each instance returned is distinct from all others. valueOf—Returns an instance that has, loosely speaking, the same value as its
parameters. Such static factories are effectively type-conversion methods.

Answer (score 4):

There is no official standard, but this is my opinion,

`valueOf` or `acquire` implies that you will get any instance which holds the same information.

`newInstance` or `create` implies you will get a different instance every time.

`get` implies you will get an instance if it exist, or `null` if it does not.

In your case `newInstance` or `create` is appropriate.

c.f.

```
Integer.valueOf(1) == Integer.valueOf(1) // you get the same object
Integer.valueOf(-200) != Integer.valueOf(-200) // you get a different object.
```

Comment: @stakx Integer doesn't have a newInstance method. The point of `valueOf` is it may or may not create a new instance; don't assume anything.

Comment: I see. But then, perhaps, using `Integer` is not the best example since it *appears to* contradict what is said before - IMHO the example should also include `newInstance`.

Comment: @stakx I don't see the contradiction. It illustrates that it may or may not create a new objects.

Answer (score 0):

In general, in java, String.valueOf() is called when a string representation of some other type of data is needed. In the case of primitive wrappers (Integer, Double), valueOf() takes a String ("12") and creates an instance of that wrapper.

In your case, you try to create a new object using a number of parameters. That is a factory method. It makes more sense to call it newInstance.

Comment: For all the wrappers valueOf() can also take a primitive. c.f. BigDecimal.valueOf(double) and valueOf(long)

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question when you said `And If I want to provide a static factory method to creating instances of this class`
new Instance makes sense in this context (even if both valueOf and new do the same). To me valueOf (as the name suggests )makes sense when you want to retrieve some meaningful state information from an existing object (not necessarily the entire object state)   where as `new` is creating brand new instance.